# MariaDB subqueries to same table and column resulting in several columns

Tags: mariadb

I have a table and want to pick monthly minute data to compare column wize in 10.3.13-MariaDB

Tested and tested for hours and hours different approaches without success, one example is below. Some tests does not complain syntactically but takes forever, and some tests complains about column names not recognized. All subqueries if tested separately return the same number of records, each in one column.

```
SELECT RD, OT1, OT2, OT3 FROM
(SELECT rdate from  OO where month(rdate) = 7 and year(rdate) = 2006) AS RD,
(SELECT ot from OO where month(rdate)=7 and year(rdate) =2006) AS OT1,
(SELECT ot from OO where month(rdate)=7 and year(rdate) =2007) AS OT2,
(SELECT ot from OO where month(rdate)=7 and year(rdate) =2008) AS OT3;`
```

The result should be something like:

```
RD                   OT1    OT2    OT3
2006-07-01 00:00:00  1.2345 2.1234 1.543
...                  ...    ...    ...
2006-07-31 23:59:00  3.456  3.234  2.234
```

And, no I dont want to use UNION because then they will still follow one after the other...

Any thoughts?!

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: What is an issue precisely? too many output rows? no output rows? some error message is returned? something else? *All subqueries if tested separately return the same number of records* Prognosis - too many rows. Cause - no joining conditions.

Comment: I have a lot of memory and have tested with smaller chunks, to no avail. In this particular case I have no error messages. In other tests I get errors indicating that it does not know the names of the columns. I dont know if the link is lost between the names in te AS statements and the first SELECT where the names are listed, as ordinary column names.

I have seen, but dont recall where: You could use subqueries instead of joins, especially since the rdate comes from 2006 and has no direct joinable part with 2007 or 2008. '2006-07-01 00:00:00' = '2007-07-01 00:00:00' for a join?

Comment: Best case - the syntax is wrong "Subqueries returns more than 1 row". Works if subqueries returns results of an aggregate. So not useful. Have to create some sort of index on "month-day hour:minute", or similar approach.

Answer (score 0):

You are pivoting too soon.  Do the union, then pivot the results.